# How to create rooms with nestjs and socket.io

Tags: node.js, typescript, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I'm trying to create a room on my nestjs backend but can't find any information on this subject. You can find the docs [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/gateways). The docs don't seem to have anything on this subject.

```
import {
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  WebSocketServer,
  WsResponse,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Client, Server } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway({namespace: 'story'})
export class StoryEventsGateway {
  @WebSocketServer()
  server: Server;

  @SubscribeMessage('createRoom')
  createRoom(client: Client, data: string): WsResponse<unknown> {
    return { event: 'roomCreated', data };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

By changing `client: Client` to `socket: Socket` you're able to use the socket object you are used to when using [socket.io](https://socket.io/).

Here is the edited function.

```ts
import { Socket } from 'socket.io';
import { WsResponse } from '@nestjs/websockets';

createRoom(socket: Socket, data: string): WsResponse<unknown> {
  socket.join('aRoom');
  socket.to('aRoom').emit('roomCreated', {room: 'aRoom'});
  return { event: 'roomCreated', room: 'aRoom' };
}
```

Comment: This really should be in the documentation, highlighted. Thanks a lot for the info.

Comment: I agree it can be easy to overlook but for future reference if you do a search for `handleEvent(client: Socket, data: string):` on the page https://docs.nestjs.com/websockets/gateways they quickly mention accessing the socket instance.

Answer (score 8):

With the latest Nest JS update you can use this code where the room name can be sent from the front-end and it will passed on to the 'data' variable:

```
@SubscribeMessage('createRoom')
  createRoom(@MessageBody() data: string, @ConnectedSocket() client: Socket) {
    client.join(data, err => {
      if (err) {
        this.logger.error(err);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had was coming from the wrong import.

```
import { Socket } from 'socket.io-client' //wrong

import { Socket } from 'socket.io' //good


@SubscribeMessage('room')
joinRoom(socket: Socket, roomId: string) {
  socket.join(roomId);
}
```